Why does `date -d 'x years ago'` only work for some values for x?
I wanted my script to exclude items created >100 years ago, so I tried
$ date +%Y -d '100 years ago'
1924

I can put that in a variable and use it. But then I thought maybe it should be 120 years:
$ date +%Y -d '120 years ago'
date: invalid date ‘120 years ago’

Odd. Well, 115 would be Good Enough:
$ date +%Y -d '115 years ago'
1909

Um.
$ date +%Y -d '95 years ago'
date: invalid date ‘95 years ago’

Wat.
$ for y in {90..125}; do printf "$y\t"; date +%Y -d "$y years ago" 2>&1;done
90  1934
91  1933
92  1932
93  date: invalid date ‘93 years ago’
94  date: invalid date ‘94 years ago’
95  date: invalid date ‘95 years ago’
96  date: invalid date ‘96 years ago’
97  date: invalid date ‘97 years ago’
98  date: invalid date ‘98 years ago’
99  date: invalid date ‘99 years ago’
100 1924
101 1923
102 1922
103 1921
104 1920
105 1919
106 1918
107 1917
108 1916
109 1915
110 1914
111 1913
112 1912
113 1911
114 1910
115 1909
116 1908
117 date: invalid date ‘117 years ago’
118 date: invalid date ‘118 years ago’
119 date: invalid date ‘119 years ago’
120 date: invalid date ‘120 years ago’
121 date: invalid date ‘121 years ago’
122 date: invalid date ‘122 years ago’
123 date: invalid date ‘123 years ago’
124 date: invalid date ‘124 years ago’
125 date: invalid date ‘125 years ago’

Why?
$ man date |grep -C2 'w.* A.* T'
DATE STRING
       The  --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indi‐
       cating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the day.  The date string format is more complex  than
       is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

but I haven't been able find anything in info that explains it.

Somehow a different machine, same OS (Ubuntu 22.04.4), manages all those years just fine, same package coreutils 8.32-4.1ubuntu1.2 amd64. While my friend's Ubuntu manages 2-114 fine but not anything over …

EDIT: As https://stackoverflow.com/users/9769953/9769953 suggests, this is related to timezones. I don't understand the mechanism though, and using anything but UTC seems like it can lead to absurd offsets:
$ TZ=Pacific/Majuro date -d '200 years ago'
fr. 16. april 19:11:20 +1124 1824
$ TZ=Pacific/Pohnpei date -d '200 years ago'
fr. 16. april 18:11:20 -1327 1824

Following the suggestion of https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk :
$ TZ=Europe/Amsterdam date --debug -d '200 years ago'
date: parsed relative part: -200 year(s)
date: input timezone: TZ="Europe/Amsterdam" environment value
date: using current time as starting value: '09:50:20'
date: using current date as starting value: '(Y-M-D) 2024-04-18'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2024-04-18 09:50:20'
date: warning: when adding relative months/years, it is recommended to specify the 15th of the months
date: error: adding relative date resulted in an invalid date: '(Y-M-D) 1824-04-18 09:50:20'
date: invalid date ‘200 years ago’

which doesn't really tell me much more, but I'm guessing the timezone simply didn't exist / isn't defined for certain date ranges.

In summary: Use date --utc as a workaround when doing "long ago" calculations.

Try with the -u option instead: date +%Y -ud '95 years ago instead. How does that work for you?

That does work! So it's a timezone thing? It can't read back past some timezone change/appearance?

Yes, I think so. The gap around 90 years ago could be due to an unknown / non-existing timezone. That's something in the internals of date. I've had a look at info date, but couldn't see anything on this particular issue.

The differences between machines is likely the same issue; check the timezones on those machines.

Yes, the one that worked fine on "all" the numbers was UTC already, mine +0100, the one that worked up until 114 was EST.
Someone else got to 15.4.1824 21.45.57 +0043  when trying 200 years ago … that's not a real UTC offset, is it?

+0043 probably was a timezone... 200 years ago. If you know the relevant country, you can try and look it up. 100 or more years ago, if time in a country was standardized at all, the timezone might not be a whole number of hours with respect to UTC. And even today, Australia has as a timezone with +8:45 offset (Australian Western Central Standard Time).

What is your timezone? What is the output of locale and readlink /etc/localtime? Inspect the output of date --debug. Also zdump <yourtimezone>.

TZ=Europe/Amsterdam date --debug -d '200 years ago' works for me. What is your locale? What is readlink /etc/localtime? What is the output zdump -v Europe/Amsterdam? What are the versions date --version zdump --version? What `"tzdata" have you installed? I am on archlinux coreutils9.5 tzdata2024a-1.

LANGUAGE=nn_NO:nn:no_NO:no:nb_NO:nb:en, the rest (LANG etc) are nn_NO.UTF-8; zdump: http://sprunge.us/An1Z04 $ readlink /etc/localtime  /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Oslo tzdata Version: 2024a-0ubuntu0.22.04
